# How can I backup and restore Wi-Fi profiles in Lion?

Tags: macos, wifi, backup

I want to reinstall my Macbook, but i do not want to loose all my saved WPA/WEP Wi-Fi profiles.

Is there a way to back them up and restore them after the reinstall?

Answer (score 4):

If you backup your keychain as well as the file `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.airport.preferences.plist`
and restore them on a new installed Lion, you won't lose them.

Another way would be to use the Migration Assistant on a Time Machine Backup of your old system, but this would restore ALL your system settings. That's probably not what you want, otherwise you wouldn't consider reinstalling.

Comment: Looking in com.apple.network.identification.plist in a text editor doesn't show any of my wifi SSIDs, but I do see them in /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.airport.preferences.plist

Comment: OK, so backup this.

Comment: Okay, so edit your answer.